# Unable to Share a 360 Image on facebook Using Facebook API

Tags: javascript, facebook

Ok so here is the problem.

I have this one 360 image which is hosted on windows azure
https://smartscreens.blob.core.windows.net/final-images/AQYPL_360.png

and i am trying to share this on Facebook using Facebook API

this is my API's Javascript code. Just using a temp link that works better because its smaller.

```
$('.btnShare').click(function () {

        var imgURL = "https://i.ibb.co/Kj9qqd7/AQYPL-360-copy.png";
        var obj = {
            method: 'feed', 
            link: imgURL,
            picture: image, 
            name: "Title", 
            description: "Description"
        };
        function callback(response) { }
        FB.ui(obj, callback);
    });
```

It Does Share the Image  But it appears as a white Screen. And it does not share it as a 360 image.

But when i download and upload the same image on Facebook. 
Facebook recognizes the image as 360. So it cant be an issue with metadata

Also when i try to only share the Link it still shows a white screen instead of rendering it as a 360 image? Thankyou for help.

Comment: Where did you get this from? `allow_spherical_photo` is not a parameter listed in the documentation of the Share dialog. The only place I can find it is in relation to uploading a photo, but that is something completely different than what you are trying here. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/

Comment: I added that accidently. it was being used in FB.api.  At the end I have reached to the conclusion that FB.api me/photos is depricated. Because Publish Actions is depricated by facebook

Comment: Also the image only apeared as white screen because FB only supports no more than 8 MB size of files when sharing.